# Is this song considered a Bebop Standard?

Tags: jazz

The following song: http://youtu.be/RiF3t1rWBv8

Is "Wrapped Tight" by Hawkins considered a bebop standard? Is he the first one to record this song? Or was it recorded earlier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After scouring the web, I unfortunately haven't been able to find any other recordings of this song. I checked Discogs, MusicBrainz, Wikipedia, JazzStandards.com, WhoSampled, etc. So, assuming that there are no other recordings, your questions should be easy to answer.

> Is "Wrapped Tight" by Hawkins considered a bebop standard?

No, since there are no other recordings.

> Is he the first one to record this song?

Yes; the composer Manny Albam must have written it for him to perform.

> Or was it recorded earlier?

No, since his was likely the first (and only) recording of the song.